# Grant SELECT to a role on Entire schema ; SYBASE

Tags: database, sybase, sap-ase

How to grant select on entire schema to a role or user in ASE 16

Answer (score 0):

Without more details I'm going to assume you're referring to the (new in `Sybase/SAP ASE 16`) `on schema` clause for the `grant` command; I hadn't actually noticed this new addition until I came across this question.

After spending 10 minutes trying several different combinations I've been unable to come up with a working version of the clause; and as you've likely noticed the documentation for the [grant command](https://help.sap.com/viewer/e0d4539d39c34f52ae9ef822c2060077/16.0.3.7/en-US/ab2e3cb3bc2b1014a4d1bcf0a81f2103.html) has no examples.

At this point I'd suggest **a)** open a case with tech support and/or **b)** post a question on the [SAP Q&A site](https://answers.sap.com/questions/ask.html) (make sure to tag your question with `SAP Adaptive Server Enterprise`) to see if someone from the SAP/ASE group can chime in with an answer.